# Spring MVC nested mapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working with Spring MVC, so I would like to do that:

http://domain.com/api/ -> main url
I have a controller is Home
request mapping: /api/home/

But it does not work. 
How can I do?

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mobile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mobile/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mobile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/m/*</url-pattern> <!-- m will be changed by mobile when finished test -->
    </servlet-mapping>
```

JAVA:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/m/home/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
            DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/m/login/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Locale locale, Model model) {
    System.out.println("Login");
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to send `/api` requests through Spring-MVC as well as `/m` requests? I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for answered my question. I solved this problem. :">
I just remove /m/ in /m/home/. With me /api and /m are the same.